# How to remove '$' sign from float dtype object but containing values with '$' sign in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dtype

I have the following `dataframe` imported from a Excel file. the columns "Market Capitalization' and 'Last Sale' both show float type but contain $ sign in front of values. I thought that is strange ( any explanation??). When I try get rid of the $ using `.replace` method it is not yielding the result as the columns are float type.

Is there a way to directly get rid of the $ sign while importing the excel sheet? Alternatively, how to remove it without actually converting the type to string format (because then I have to reconvert the columns to float again after removing the $ sign). Appreciate inputs.

```
amex = pd.read_excel('listings.xlsx', sheet_name='amex',na_values='n/a')
print(amex.info())
print(amex.head())
    
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 360 entries, 0 to 359
Data columns (total 7 columns):
#   Column                 Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------                 --------------  -----  
0   Stock Symbol           360 non-null    object 
1   Company Name           360 non-null    object 
2   Last Sale              346 non-null    float64
3   Market Capitalization  360 non-null    float64
4   IPO Year               105 non-null    float64
5   Sector                 238 non-null    object 
6   Industry               238 non-null    object 
    dtypes: float64(3), object(4)
    memory usage: 19.8+ KB
    None
    
    Stock Symbol    Company Name    Last Sale   Market Capitalization   IPO Year    Sector  Industry
0   XXII    22nd Century Group, Inc     $1.33   $120,628,490.29     $nan    Consumer Non-Durables   Farming/Seeds/Milling
1   FAX     Aberdeen Asia-Pacific Income Fund Inc   $5.00   $1,266,332,595.00   $1,986.00   NaN     NaN
2   IAF     Aberdeen Australia Equity Fund Inc  $6.15   $139,865,304.90     $nan    NaN     NaN
3   CH  Aberdeen Chile Fund, Inc.   $7.22   $67,563,457.57  $nan    NaN     NaN
4   ABE     Aberdeen Emerging Markets Smaller Company Oppo...   $13.36  $128,842,971.60     $nan    NaN     NaN
```

Comment: My apologies to everyone... After some painful scrutiny, I have noticed that somewhere in the middle of my notebook I have this command - pd.options.display.float_format = '${:,.2f}'.format, which I guess was causing the problem. I removed the $ from the command; now all is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df['Last Sale'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Last Sale'].str.replace('$', ''))
df['Market Capitalization'] = df['Market Capitalization'].str.replace('[\$,]', '', regex=True)
df['IPO Year'] = df['IPO Year'].str.replace('\$nan', '')
df['IPO Year'] = pd.to_numeric(df['IPO Year'].str.replace('[\$,]', ''))

print(df)


  Stock Symbol                                       Company Name  Last Sale Market Capitalization  IPO Year                 Sector               Industry
0         XXII                            22nd Century Group, Inc       1.33          120628490.29       NaN  Consumer Non-Durables  Farming/Seeds/Milling
1          FAX              Aberdeen Asia-Pacific Income Fund Inc       5.00         1266332595.00    1986.0                    NaN                    NaN
2          IAF                 Aberdeen Australia Equity Fund Inc       6.15          139865304.90       NaN                    NaN                    NaN
3           CH                          Aberdeen Chile Fund, Inc.       7.22           67563457.57       NaN                    NaN                    NaN
4          ABE  Aberdeen Emerging Markets Smaller Company Oppo...      13.36          128842971.60       NaN                    NaN                    NaN
```

Comment: Using regex=True solved the issue for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After the `.replace` use `.astype(float)` to cast the replace strings as float:

```
df['col_name'] = df['col_name'].str.replace('$','').astype(float)
```

Comment: I wonder why these columns show as float objects but contain string character '$'.

Comment: Also, when I convert these columns into string type just by using only the .str() method, the '$' sign disappears and when I apply pd.to_numeric to this converted object, the '$' sign reappears, though the columns get converted back to float type. Any explanations please??